# CFFILE upload Chinese filename end up with ? marks

Tags: utf-8, server, coldfusion, plesk, cffile

I have been using CFFILE to upload image files with Chinese characters in the filename, such as 图片.jpg without any issue:

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="#currentpath#" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" fileField="form.upfile" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

Recently, files started to appear as ??.jpg on the server.  However, the name are stored properly in the database.  This means that CFFILE is getting the file name properly.  But the uploaded file ended up as ??.jpg on the server.  I am totally lost as to why all of a sudden it stopped working.  The tech support is also lost.

I am wondering if this is a Coldfusion issue or the Plesk Unix server issue?  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: No solution, but a few things to consider: check the output of `locale` on the server. Check if Java is set to use UTF-8 (JVM Argument). Even check your terminal application, if it's configured correctly and displays the filename correctly when you create a testfile via `touch 图片.test`. If you are running CF2016 check if this bug may be involved in the issue: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198841

Comment: @Seybsen I noticed under the Setting Summary, the "Java File Encoding" field is ASCII and the "Java Default Locale" is en_US.  Could this be the issue?  If yes, where do I set it?

Comment: @Seybsen that was the issue.  Don't know how that CF setting got changed.  If you want to put it as a solution so I can give you the credit and help others.  Thank you.